# RuntimeError occurs randomly on pyqgis loop

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I wrotee a loop in pyqgis 3 to apply processing to each polygon of a layer.
Apparently randomly, a RuntimeError occurs and crashes my script.

Here is the loop part of my script, with the first processing :

```
for feature in features :
    feature_id = feature.id()
    nonbati.selectByIds([feature_id])
    temp_layer = QgsVectorLayer('MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:2154', "temporary_polygons", "memory")
    crs = temp_layer.crs()
    crs.createFromId(2154)
    temp_layer.setCrs(crs)
    selection = nonbati.selectedFeatures()
    temp_data = temp_layer.dataProvider()
    attr = nonbati.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    temp_data.addAttributes(attr)
    temp_layer.updateFields()
    temp_data.addFeatures(selection)

    # Tampon
    alg_params = {
        'DISSOLVE': False,
        'DISTANCE': 0.5,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'INPUT': temp_layer,
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['Tampon'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

Error always occur on the 10th line :

```
attr = nonbati.dataProvider().fields().toList()
```

Here is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\moulin_z\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\iteration_while_1706_fonctionne.py", line 63, in processAlgorithm
attr = nonbati.dataProvider().fields().toList()
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorDataProvider has been deleted
```

I don't understand why this error sometimes occurs, or how fix it.

Comment: What happens if you move that line outside of your loop so that you get and store just one reference to your nonbati layer fields? I don't think you need to do it for every feature inside the loop.

Comment: oh I didn't think about that, actually I probably do not need to repeat this line with each loop... thank's